# Create factorial column based on same text in rownames in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have this example of dataframe.

```
df <- structure(list(PC1 = c(-0.0277818345657933, -0.0342426301759117, 
-0.0328199061848987, 0.0557338197779853, 0.042369402931087), 
    PC2 = c(-0.0149291182738773, -0.00862145986823889, -0.0101822421485786, 
    -0.00862630869071877, -0.00419434673647331)), row.names = c("Homo sapiens - ULAC-0968", 
"Homo sapiens - ULAC-0978", "Homo sapiens - ULAC-0996", "Pan troglodytes - HTB2804", 
"Pan troglodytes - HTB411"), class = "data.frame")
```

What I would like is to create an extra column, named `Species`, with the content of the row names. In this case, the factors would be only `Homo sapiens` and `Pan troglodytes`.

How could I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
rownames_to_column(var = 'Species') %>%
mutate(Species=sapply(strsplit(Species,split = ' -'),function(x) as.factor(x[1])))
```

**output;**

```
 Species             PC1      PC2
  <fct>             <dbl>    <dbl>
1 Homo sapiens    -0.0278 -0.0149 
2 Homo sapiens    -0.0342 -0.00862
3 Homo sapiens    -0.0328 -0.0102 
4 Pan troglodytes  0.0557 -0.00863
5 Pan troglodytes  0.0424 -0.00419
```

Comment: That's perfect! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Base R option.

Use `sub` to drop everything from `-` and delete the rownames.

```
df$Species <- trimws(sub('-.*', '', rownames(df)))
rownames(df) <- NULL
df

#      PC1      PC2         Species
#1 -0.0278 -0.01493    Homo sapiens
#2 -0.0342 -0.00862    Homo sapiens
#3 -0.0328 -0.01018    Homo sapiens
#4  0.0557 -0.00863 Pan troglodytes
#5  0.0424 -0.00419 Pan troglodytes
```